# I want to download Ubuntu 13.04 but I can not to do it

Tags: installation, downloads

I love Ubuntu and I use it since 1985. I decided to download Ubuntu 13.04 but I'm a rookie. If you can send me a CD with that version I would be happiest.

Comment: **Ubuntu** since 1985!? Really?

Comment: where do we send it?

Comment: Please be more specific why you can't download it. Did you get an error message?

Comment: Do you live in the drains between Manhattan and New Jersey since 1985 ?   ;-)   - top secret ?! - how to send you a CD/DVD ? - need some address for it - e-mail is given when you click at my nick ...

Comment: How can you still be a noob after using Ubuntu for 28 years?

Comment: First Ubuntu is 4.10 (Warty Warthog), released October, 20 2004.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Canonical [no longer](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit) sends free CDs. However, you can buy CDs from Canonical's [shop](https://shop.canonical.com/) but they only send packs of 5, 20, 100 or 200 CDs.

Alternatively, some of the commentators seem to be willing to send you one. You didn't mention how the download failed, but you could also try to [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) the file again from Ubuntu's website and then [create](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) a live USB disk, the link has instructions for both Windows, and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting your nearest [Loco Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeams) there is a list [here](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/).  They may be able to able send you a CD (perhaps at a nominal cost to cover postage and packaging.

Canonical do sell CDs/DVDs via there [shop](http://shop.canonical.com/) but they stopped making these with Ubuntu 12.10 except for LTS (Long Term Stable) releases and 13.04 is not an LTS release so is not available.

The easiest way to get Ubuntu should be to download it.  You can get it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/)

Make sure you check the MD5sum to check the was no error in the transfer and make a DVD or USB stick to install from.

Instructions on checking the MD5 sum are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Instructions to create a [DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) or [USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)